# Narrowing Integrated Windows Authentication to a subset of users for an intranet ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, authentication, windows-authentication

**Scenario:**  An intranet ASP.Net application using Integrated Windows Authentication and a SqlRoleProvider for authorization.  The application is used by a small subset of users within the domain.

If there are only a few users within the domain that should be able to access the application, can IWA be narrowed to allow authentication for that subset of users only, say via a domain group?  Is this possible or even logical?  This would certainly be the case if you predefined user accounts and used forms authentication.  I understand that you can manage authorization within the application but wonder if the above is possible to add some security in depth.  Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: what do you mean by using Integrated Windows Authentication  for authorization?

Comment: I am only using Integrated Windows for Authentication.  I am using the SqlRoleProvider held roles for authorization.

Comment: What are your concerns, here?  Authenticating someone is generally a small overhead and, unless they're authorised, gives them no access to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

With anonymous access disabled, you can set the NTFS permissions on the web application directory to let only specific users in.

Answer (score 1):

IWA will authenticate all valid users. But you can do the following,

- allocate the subset of users into a group, and use role rrovider for them. Then you can allow only this group to use the application.
- Or use forms authentication instead and write your own membership provider to authenticate users. Then you have all the controls and can block unwanted users.

Comment: So the only way to manage the access to the application in this scenario is in fact through role authorization since all valid users will authenticate?

Comment: Yes, you must do something after the authentication phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try some of the more traditional authorization techniques I outlined here:

[Is it possible to restrict windows authenticated users in an ASPNet app to specific domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878139/is-it-possible-to-restrict-windows-authenticated-users-in-an-aspnet-app-to-specif/4036810#4036810)